# What are the new constants for the PDFFontFactory class in itext?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am would like to utilize the PdfFontFactory library from iText7; however, I can no longer use FontConstants (i.e. FontConstants.COURIER). These constants have been marked deprecated, but I can't find what I should replace this with.

This program makes use of iText7 (the libraries also use slf4j). I have tried creating my own font, but this makes use of the Font class, which I am unsure where I should import the constants from (First attempt was java.awt, which didn't work). I have also tried making up my own values for the parameters, and I have tried using the parameter-less version you see earlier in the code. I got this code and constants from the iText tutorial: https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-java/chapter-5-manipulating-existing-pdf-document

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = null;
        try {
            pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourcePDF), new PdfWriter(destPDF));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PdfAnnotation ann = new PdfTextAnnotation(new Rectangle(400, 795, 0, 0))
                .setTitle(new PdfString("iText"))
                .setContents("Please, fill out the form.");
            pdfDoc.getFirstPage().addAnnotation(ann);
            PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.getFirstPage());
            canvas.beginText().setFontAndSize(
                    PdfFontFactory.createFont(), 12)
                    .moveText(265, 597)
                    .showText("I agree to the terms and conditions.")
                    .endText();
            PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
            Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.getFormFields();
            fields.get("language").setValue("English");
            fields.get("experience1").setValue("Yes");
            fields.get("experience2").setValue("Yes");
            fields.get("experience3").setValue("Yes");
            fields.get("shift").setValue("Any");
            PdfFont courier = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.COURIER);
            fields.get("info")
                .setValue("I was 38 years old when I became a 007 agent.", courier, 7);
            pdfDoc.close();
```

I do not get any errors when running with this code, but eclipse throws a few warnings because of the deprecated values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

itext has deprecated original FontConstants.java and moved all fonts related constants to **com.itextpdf.io.font.constants** so you can use below options in place of FontConstants.java.

https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/7.1.2/com/itextpdf/io/font/constants/StandardFontFamilies.html

https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/7.1.2/com/itextpdf/io/font/constants/StandardFonts.html

Answer (score 6):

You can now use **StandardFonts** instead of **FontConstants**.

```
PdfFont courier = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.COURIER);
```